# Computer goes to sleep right after waking it up using WOL

Tags: windows-7, power, hibernate, suspend

I have been having issues with WOL on this particular Windows 7 64bit HTPC computer. The hybrid sleep option is on, however it should never go to sleep on its own ("sleep after" is set to 0).

When I turn on the computer using the physical power button, the computer turns on and stays on as long as I let it.

When I turn it on using a WOL command, the computer turns on, but roughly 2-3 minutes later it goes to sleep - the only way I can prevent this is to start playing a movie right away, but soon as I pause it, it sleeps.

In the event viewer, the message listed was something like "computer entering sleep due to idle time"

I've read a [similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/124772/windows-7-goes-to-sleep-in-conflict-with-power-option-setting) were it was suggested that Win 7 has some additional hidden power settings within the registry. If the computer is awoken remotely (as in the WOL case) it has no idea why it was awoken and goes back to sleep. I erased both registry keys mentioned in the thread, but this hasn't solved my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have solved the problem. Rather than deleting the registry keys, I have added them back and set them all to "0" which pretty much disables this power feature. It's been more than 5 minutes since my computer turned on after a wol event.

Update: after a few days with the new settings, the issue never returned!