# Windows 10 entering sleep against Power Plan settings + WSDPrintDevice appears in Event Viewer

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My Win 10 laptop is supposed to serve as a server for another machine.  So it needs to stay awake even if I am not on it.  This is not happening and the machine may work for 2-3 hours or sleep after 5 minutes.  No real pattern.

I have reset and tweaked Power Settings Plans to no great results.

What I do in the Events Viewer logs is:

```
Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock."
Information 2017-07-07 4:15:55 PM   Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power  107 (102)   The system has resumed from sleep.
Information 2017-07-07 4:15:53 PM   Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power  42  (64)    "The system is entering sleep.

Sleep Reason: System Idle"
Information 2017-07-07 4:15:53 PM   Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power  40  (36)    The driver \Driver\WSDPrintDevice for device SWD\DAFWSDProvider\urn:uuid:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c03575f/uri:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c03575f/PrinterService stopped the power transition.
```

The bit that is interesting is that **\Driver\WSDPrintDevice** always shows up before **Sleep Reason: System Idle**.  I've disabled my printer driver, but that must not have been it because it's still happening.

I ve looked around some of the, many, sleep questions, but haven't found WSDPrintDevice mentioned.

How do I update/disable WSDPrintDevice?

Then again, maybe the WSDPrint is trying to resist going to sleep, rather than causing it.

As a work around, found @ http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=42, I am running `powercfg -h off` in the **admin** powershell console to disable sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

See the same question for Win7 [Windows 7 Goes to Sleep in conflict with Power Option Setting](https://superuser.com/questions/124772/windows-7-goes-to-sleep-in-conflict-with-power-option-setting)

There it is, if you have hibernation enabled, there is an advanced setting deep down that specifies hibernation timer and the system sleeps though the main settings window shows Sleep Never.  The WSDPrintDevice is totally innocent for this issue.