# Cannot start laptop going to sleep non-stop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep

My laptop went to sleep mode and after a while I tried to turn it on and when it's about to start goes back to sleep. Even when I shut down when I try to turn it on just when it's about to show desktop it goes to sleep again. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Can you load into windows to check the settings and change the power plan? Can load into safe mode? Do you have power connected / battery charged?

Comment: Check your question is not a duplicate, see if this resolves it if you can get into Windows https://superuser.com/questions/124772/windows-7-goes-to-sleep-in-conflict-with-power-option-setting